# how to add type information in Json serialization in Angular 7

Tags: json, angular, serialization

how to add type information in Json serialization in Angular 7

Hello everybody, I need to add type information at Json serialization in Angular 7 in order to get this result (adding the line "$type": "Person",):

```
{
    "$type": "Person",
    "id": 8,
    "firstName": "Anke",
    "lastName": "Winkler",
    …
}
```

I need this in order to deserialize in C# with Json.NET and knowing which type to use in case of properties that are typed with an interface and thus may be of different types. Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: The same way you add any other property to your JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not much an Angular serialization issue, but more a TypeScript/JavaScript issue.

You can customize your serialization by overriding the `toJSON()` method in your TypeScript classes.

```
class User {
  public id: number;
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;
  public age: number;

  public toJSON(): User {
    return Object.assign({}, this, {
      $type: 'User'
    });
  }
}
```

What the `toJSON()` method will do, is simply create a new object using the current one, and the add the `$type` property to it. It will be called when you call the `JSON.stringify()` method. Thus, you don't need to create a `$type` variable in your class.

Example:

```
const newUser: User = new User();

newUser.id = 8;
newUser.firstName = "John";
newUser.lastName = "Doe";
newUser.age = 42;

const newUserAsJson: string = JSON.stringify(newUser);

console.log(newUserAsJson);
// Displays:
// {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", id: 8, age: 42, $type: "User"}
```

Hope it helps.