# Angular 2+: can I make a getter appear as part of my POST body?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 11 I want a getter of mine to be used in a POST body. It looks to me as if the getter should appear in the POST body because it appears in `for (let x of myObj) ...`, but it is not to be found in the POST body.

```js
/* Here's my class with a getter */
class Foo {
  #privateField?: string;

  get publicField(): string|undefined {
    return this.#privateField;
  }

  set publicField(value: string|undefined) {
    this.#privateField = value; // The real implementation has data-massaging here
  }
}

/* Make a member enumerable so that it appears in `for (let key in obj) ...` */
Object.defineProperty(Consumer.prototype, 'publicField', {enumerable: true});


/* Make a POST using the Foo */
const foo: Foo = retreiveFoo(form);
this.http.post<FooResponse>('/foo.json', foo); // Request using HttpClient
```

I've added an HttpInterceptor so that I can have a peek, and in fact, `publicField` does show up in the console log, albeit its value appears as "`...`". Clicking the ellipsis value transforms it into the string value that I expected to see to begin with.

```js
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(req.body)
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Examining the browser devtools Network tab confirms that `publicField` is *not* being sent. **Is there a way for me to send the getter's in the POST (with the getter's name as the key)?**

Comment: [Add a custom toJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55322213/7711863) to the class?